# Unexpected behavior with knockout with foreach: the data-abide-validator no longer validates when using foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

The below foreach snippet is inside a form. The issue is that normally the data-abide-validator gets triggered as you type with knockout. However, in this specific case where we have foreach, the answerValidationRule only gets triggered on submit of the form.

```html
<form data-abide="ajax" id="someForm" autocomplete="off">
  <div data-bind="foreach: question">
    <label for="answerX">Answer</label>
    <input id="answerX" type="text" data-bind="attr: {id: 'answer_' + $index()} " data-abide-validator="answerValidationRule" />
  </div>
  <button id="continue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can someone please shed some light why this is happening and whether there is a clean workaround for this. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What is `data-abide`?  I suspect it's probably because it's on a dynamically generated element so whatever library is using the `data-abide` attributes doesn't see it during initialisation.  You may need some sort of custom binding between the two.

Comment: Thanks James, trying to use onChange or listening to keystroke and triggering the validation method manually. Definitely works that way, just hoping there is a cleaner solution.